# float elements not in div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple CSS layout. In my div content, I want to split it into two section using float. However, despite putting my float elements in my div content, it does not stay inside.

[image]

```css
.content {
  border: 5px solid #0099CC;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>This is my content page</p>
  <div class="left">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>User Login</legend>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Main Area</legend>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I removed the float, my fieldset will be in my div content. So I suspect it could be my float CSS that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div> after completing 'right' div
```

```css
.content {
    border: 5px solid #0099CC;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>This is my content page</p>
    <div class="left">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User Login</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Main Area</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.right` class if you have already used `float: left`

```css
.content {
    border: 5px solid #0099CC;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>This is my content page</p>
    <div class="left">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User Login</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Main Area</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` in your `.content`

```
.content {
border: 5px solid #0099CC;
width: 90%;
min-width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
```

}